# jQuery: slideDown() slides back up

Tags: jquery, html, slidedown

I have a hardy reproducible issue with a

sliding back up circa 50% of the time after it slidesDown(). The jQuery code is extremely simple:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var slideOptions = {
    duration: 500,
    easing: 'linear'
};

$( 'li.navtitle' ).mouseenter(function() {
    $( this ).next().slideDown();
    return false;
});
$( 'ul.navunit' ).mouseleave(function() {
    $( this ).find( 'li.navcontent' ).delay(800).slideUp();
    return false;
});
});
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<ul id="navigation">
  <li class="navtop">   
    <ul class="navunit">
      <li class="navtitle unselectable" unselectable="on">TITLE</li>
      <li class="navcontent"><p class="textcontent">CONTENT HERE</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
<!-- Some more navtop/navunits... -->
</ul>
```

As said, this works circa 50% of the time. However, in many cases the navcontent li will slideUp() while the mouse is inside the navunit ul.

Anyone a clue as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I should probably note that the return false; is something I tried to fix the issue which doesn't work, it should be removed from the code.

Comment: I bet the core issue is the `.delay()`. If you move the mouse outside the element and back again within the 800 ms, the delay timer triggers the slideup.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to add a `stop()` to the animations. The JS code is below but here's a link to JSFiddle to see it in action http://jsfiddle.net/MDpxD/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var slideOptions = {
    duration: 500,
    easing: 'linear'
};

$( 'li.navtitle' ).mouseenter(function() {
    $( this ).next().stop().slideDown();
    return false;
});
$( 'ul.navunit' ).mouseleave(function() {
    $( this ).find( 'li.navcontent' ).stop().delay(800).slideUp();
    return false;
});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This probably happens because it triggers twice. Try to add this to the end of your function:

```
    $(this).unbind("mouseenter");
$(this).unbind("bind");
$(this).die();
```